# Core Data adding relationship by users

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am stuck on a issue that I am having with core data, Once my app load the core data database gets create. I have a user entity that gets populated via the submit button on the login viewController if the credentials are correct. In the next View I take the return data from the login viewController and submit it to another URL. This gives me `JSON` return data which gets stored in the database as well.

I have attached my data model and everything work fine except the user entity, I cannot for the life of me to get the right user to go with the data inside the connections.

[image: datamodel]

These are my users 
[image: users]

Each user has two records the below is what's getting stored, instead of all all 1's in the user column there should be two 1's and two 2's.

[image: table]

Here is my code that I am using to store the data

```
  User *username = [User MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"username" withValue:currentUser];
  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"DeviceKey": username.guid};

 [_operationManager POST:@"GetPrivateRssFeeds" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

  //I'm calling all the users with this piece
  NSArray *elements = [User MR_findAll];
  id attributes = [elements  valueForKey:@"username"];

  NSLog(@"user: %@",attributes);
  username.sessionKey =[[operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"Data"]objectForKey:@"sessionId"];

  id connections = [[operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"Data"]objectForKey:@"connections"];
  id connection;

   NSMutableArray *connectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  for(connection in connections)
  {
      //Get the JSON values
      NSString *contentSystemID = [connection objectForKey:@"contentSystemId"];
      NSString *contentSystemName = [connection objectForKey:@"name"];
      NSString *logoUrl =  [connection objectForKey:@"logo"];
      NSNumber *unreadCount = [connection objectForKey:@"unread_count"];

      FCConnection *connectionEntity = [FCConnection MR_createEntity];
      connectionEntity.contentSystemID   = contentSystemID;
      connectionEntity.contentSystemName = contentSystemName;
      connectionEntity.logoUrl = logoUrl;
      connectionEntity.unreadCount = unreadCount;

    // [user addConnections:connection];
       [connectionArray addObject:connection];

      id categories = [connection objectForKey:@"categories"];

      NSMutableArray *categoryArray = [NSMutableArray array];

      for (id cat in categories)
      {
          NSString *title = [cat valueForKey:@"name"];
          NSNumber *unreadCount = [cat valueForKey:@"unread_count"];


          FCCategory *category = [FCCategory MR_createEntity];
          category.title = title;
          category.unreadCount = unreadCount;


          id items = [cat objectForKey:@"items"];




          NSMutableArray *itemArray = [NSMutableArray array];

          for (id item in items)
          {

              NSNumber *isRead = [item valueForKey:@"unread"];
              NSString *title = [item valueForKey:@"title"];
              NSString *link = [item valueForKey:@"link"];
              NSString *systemID = [item valueForKey:@"itemId"];
             // BaseTopic *baseEntity = [A MR_createEntity];
             // baseEntity.title   = title;
              Article *article = [Article MR_createEntity];
              article.link = link;
              article.systemID = systemID;
              article.isRead = isRead;

              [article setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
              article.category = category;

              [itemArray addObject:article];
                NSLog(@"item %@",itemArray);
          }

          [category addArticles:[NSSet setWithArray:itemArray]]; // mapping the items to category
           category.connection = connectionEntity;
          [categoryArray addObject:category];
      }

      connectionEntity.user = username;
      [connectionEntity addCategories:[NSSet setWithArray:categoryArray]]; // mapping the items to connection entity
```

How can I map the user to the connection?

Comment: are you sure your `currentUser` is set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the same user entity (i.e., username) for all the connections you are enumerating in that loop (for(connection in connections)). Hence why, It's all set to 1. Set the user entity properly based on your logic.